Pytorch.autograd.grad showing error "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType"
I'm trying to find my velocity field gradients by using torch.autograd. Initially I assigned my domain co-ordinates by a function named 'generate_coords', then I passed this to 'compute_gradients' function to calculate the gradients. My velocity field shape is [30,2,32,32] (2 channels is for both Ux and Uy).
This is the code I've used to compute the gradients:
def generate_coords(height, width, x_max, y_max):
    x = torch.linspace(0, x_max, width)
    y = torch.linspace(0, y_max, height)
    xx, yy = torch.meshgrid(x, y, indexing='ij')
    coords = torch.stack([xx, yy], dim=0)
    coords = coords.unsqueeze(0)  
    return coords

def compute_gradients(U, coords):
    U = U.requires_grad_()
    coords = coords.requires_grad_()

    Ux = U[:, 0, :, :]  # Extracting Ux component
    Uy = U[:, 1, :, :]  # Extracting Uy component

    x_coords = coords[:, 0, :, :]  # Extracting x coordinates
    y_coords = coords[:, 1, :, :]  # Extracting y coordinates

    # Computing the gradients
    grad_Ux_x = torch.autograd.grad(outputs=Ux, inputs=x_coords, grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(Ux), create_graph=True, allow_unused=True)[0]
    grad_Uy_y = torch.autograd.grad(outputs=Uy, inputs=y_coords, grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(Uy), create_graph=True, allow_unused=True)[0]
    
    # Computing residuals
    residuals = grad_Ux_x + grad_Uy_y

    return residuals

coords = generate_coords(32, 32, 2520, 504) 
grad_Ux_x, grad_Uy_y = compute_gradients(torch.tensor(actual_image_inputs_test), coords)
print(grad_Ux_x, grad_Uy_y)

But showing this error:
`TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[98], line 29
     26     return residuals
     28 coords = generate_coords(32, 32, 2520, 504) 
---> 29 grad_Ux_x, grad_Uy_y = compute_gradients(torch.tensor(actual_image_inputs_test), coords)
     30 print(grad_Ux_x, grad_Uy_y)

Cell In[98], line 24, in compute_gradients(U, coords)
     21 grad_Uy_y = torch.autograd.grad(outputs=Uy, inputs=y_coords, grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(Uy), create_graph=True, allow_unused=True)[0]
     23 # Computing residuals
---> 24 residuals = grad_Ux_x + grad_Uy_y
     26 return residuals

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType`


The error is close to residuals = grad_Ux_x + grad_Uy_y, I suspect that both variables are None, meaning that the gradient is not computed correctly. Put this line before residuals = grad_Ux_x + grad_Uy_y to debug it: import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace(). You may need to install that package: pip install ipdb. Also, can you provide the shape of torch.tensor(actual_image_inputs_test)?

The shape of the actual_image_inputs_test is [30, 2, 32, 32] (2 channels is for both Ux and Uy). I tried by importing this like ""ipdb.set_trace()"". I found nothing is showing for 'grad_Ux_x' and 'grad_Uy_y'. That means  gradient is not computed. What could be the reason?

Can you share a small example, assigning values to all input tensors, and give the expected output? I am not sure what is the function. Typically, when you want to get the gradient of a function f, the input tensor x is defined as x = torch.tensor(values, requires_grad=True), where requires_grad=True tells Torch to track that variable when computing the gradient. Then, call y = f(x) to evaluate the function, then y.backward() to compute the gradient, and x.grad to get the gradient.

Check this notebook https://github.com/deep-learning-with-pytorch/dlwpt-code/blob/master/p1ch5/2_autograd.ipynb. In that example, loss = loss_fn(t_p, t_c), the authors want to compute the gradient of t_p with respect to loss_fn, where t_p = model(t_u, *params). Note that params is the only tensor created using requires_grad=True. That means when you call loss.backward(), you can get the gradient of params by using params.grad.

I checked your recommended code and understood how they used loss.backward(), but they didn't sue torch.autograd.grad directly. As, I used torch.autograd.grad , which returns the gradients, do I still follow that architecture? Actually, this is one small part of my entire code. My expectation is that I have my velocity fields in the shape of [30, 2, 32, 32] (30 samples and 2 channels for Ux and Uy) and I just need to find the gradient of my velocity fields. Like (del_Ux/del_x and del_Uy/del_y)-- Continuity equation.
